# Uninstalling my app from the device makes it so that I can no longer run it from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, device, google-pixel

I can deploy a fresh hello world app no problem (as long as it's not with the same name/namespace as one I've already uninstalled from the device). However, the moment that I uninstall the app (accidentally admittedly) I can no longer just run and I see this error in its place:

```
$ adb shell am start -n "com.ld.hello_android/com.ld.hello_android.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.ld.hello_android/com.ld.hello_android.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.ld.hello_android/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.ld.hello_android/com.ld.hello_android.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Seems this is unique to my Pixel 3. I wasn't able to replicate this behavior on my Nexus 6p. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this issue is, for whatever reason, specific to my device (Pixel 3). Another device (same Pixel 3) as well as a Nexus 6P I keep around do not display this behavior. I managed to address this problem on my device by running the `uninstallDebug` gradle task before trying to run the app again.